# Remove everything before digits in R

Tags: r, regex, substring

I need to remove all non-digits from a specific column:

Raw data example: `â‚¬42,990`
I need to remove everything before the digits kindly note, there is no space, so the result would be: `42,990`

I have tried and it worked, but I am sure it can be written in a better way.

```
df$PriceinGermany <- sub(pattern = ".*?\\D\\D\\D",replace=" ", df$PriceinGermany)
```

Comment: `pattern="\\D+"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extract the number from the text you can use `parse_number` from `readr` which can do this without regex.

```
x <- 'â‚¬42,990'
readr::parse_number(x)
#[1] 42990
```

Use `df$PriceinGermany <- readr::parse_number(df$PriceinGermany)` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove any chars other than digits from the beginning (start) of string, you can use

```r
sub("^\\D+", "", x)
```

In your code,

```r
df$PriceinGermany <- sub("^\\D+", "", df$PriceinGermany)
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\D+` - one or more non-digit chars.